# Weak convergence and generating function

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, convergence-divergence, generating-functions, weak-convergence

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of $\mathbb N_0$ valued random variables and denote by $g_{X_n}$ their generating function, i.e. $g_{X_n}(s) = \mathbb E[s^{X_n}] = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} s^k \mathbb P(X_n=k)$.

I want to show that

$$X_n \rightarrow X \text{ weakly} \Leftrightarrow g_{X_n} \rightarrow g_{X} \text{ pointwise on } [0,1]$$

It boils down to exchanging limit in $X_n$ and the expectation value, but neither monotone convergence nor dominated convergence theorem are applicable.

How can one proof the above statement?

Comment: edited: on $[0,1]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that for random variables with values in $\Bbb N$, $X_n\to X$ weakly is equivalent to 
$$\tag{C}\forall k\in\Bbb N,\quad \lim_{n\to +\infty} P(X_n=k)=P(X=k).$$
We thus have to show that this condition is equivalent to 
$$\tag{C'}\forall s\in [0,1],\quad \lim_{n\to +\infty} g_{X_n}(s)=g_X(s).$$
Assume that (C) holds. We have pointwise convergence for $s=1$ by definition of a probability measure; for $0\leqslant s<1$, we use the fact that $\sum_ks^k$ is convergent: 
$$|g_{X_n}(s)-g_X(s)|\leqslant \sum_{k=1}^Ns^k|P(X_n=k)-P(X=k)|+\sum_{k\geqslant N+1}s^k.$$
Conversely, assume that (C') holds. Integrating and using the dominated convergence theorem, one can show that for each integer $p$, we have 
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}P(X_n=k)\frac 1{(k+1)^p}=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}P(X=k)\frac 1{(k+1)^p},$$
and by an approximation argument, we can show that for each $f\in C[0,1]$, 
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}P(X_n=k)f\left(\frac 1{k+1}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}P(X=k)f\left(\frac 1{k+1}\right).$$
From this, one can conclude convergence in law.

Comment: Thanks! In your last statement, why does $f_n$ converge uniformly on $U$? For a holomorphic function, is pointwise convergence on a compact subset of $U$ enough to guarantee this?

Comment: @madison54 I don't see now why there would be uniform convergence (there is, we can say that _a posteriori_). I think I have an other argument which should work.

Comment: I see your argument in the first step, which is basically the polynomials are dense in the continuous functions, but why does convergence in law follow from the last line? 
Do you see an argument which follows the following intuition (no reference to probability at all needed): look at the $\mathbb P(X_n=k)$ as some coefficient. For $s=1$ the sums of the coefficients are equal, but not pointwise equal. But, if one has equality on a compact set, i.e. infinitely many values, then one can compare every coefficient.

Comment: Take $g\colon [1,+\infty)$ a continuous function which vanishes at infinity, then define $f(x):=g(1/x)$, a continuous function on $[0,1]$.